# C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {


    int arr[3][3]{ {11, 2, 4}, {4, 5 ,6}, {10, 8, -12} };

    int ArrayLength = sqrt(sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int));
    int difference{ 0 };


    int primaryDiagonal = arr[0][0];
    for (int i = 1; i < ArrayLength; i++) {
        primaryDiagonal = primaryDiagonal + arr[i][i];
    }

    int secondaryDiagonal = arr[0][ArrayLength - 1];
    for (int i = 1; i < ArrayLength; i++) {
        secondaryDiagonal = secondaryDiagonal + arr[i][ArrayLength - (i + 1)];
    }


    difference = primaryDiagonal - secondaryDiagonal;


    cout << abs(difference);


    return 0;
```

I've been trying to get this code to work but I keep getting the warning getting treated as an error. To my understanding, it says that since the function sqrt() is defined to return a double, it should be initiated as a double to prevent errors of conversion.
The code will work correctly if we ignored the error. But I just want to know if there's a fix to it.

I've tried initializing ArrayLength as Double but I get another error in other lines of code where it is used saying that it needs to be of integral type.

Comment: try: `    int ArrayLength = static_cast<int>(sqrt(sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int)));
`

Comment: obviously very rarely `sqrt` returns an integer, so it must return a floating-point type. If you're sure that in your case you always get an integer value then simply cast the result to int

Comment: That did work! Thank you! No errors or warnings.

Is it possible to briefly explain why this one works by any chance?

Comment: Why are you using C-style arrays in C++ in 2022? Use `std::array` instead.

Comment: Ok I think I get it now. So 'static_cast' basically force converted it to 'int' type.

Comment: I'm pretty new to all of this. It's been a while since I touched any code. I'm still trying to get my head wrapped around it. 
Thank you though, I'll keep that in mind!

Answer (score 2):

The result of `sqrt` is a double and you're initialising an `int` with it. Hence the complaint.

If you know the entire thing is a square matrix (and the `sqrt` "solution" seems to indicate this), you can just use one of:

```c
int ArrayLength = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
int ArrayLength = sizeof(arr[0]) / sizeof(int);
```

Although it *probably* should be `size_t` rather than `int`. The former is a more natural type for size/quantity of something.

Comment: but that way you won't silent the warning. Besides it's better rounding the result, because `sqrt` may return a slightly smaller value, like 22.9999... which will make a smaller array when doing a simple truncation

Comment: Apologies, @phuclv, I had mistakenly left the `sqrt` in when I cut and pasted but it's actually not needed. Latest update fixes that.